# -Dlog4j.formatMsgNoLookups=true OR -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true - which is correct?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

Which one is correct?

- -Dlog4j.formatMsgNoLookups=true
- -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true

Or both are working?
**Ref:**
log4j: https://dev.to/composite/how-to-pass-the-log4j2-vulnerability-quick-453h

log4j2: 1) https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot
2) https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2021-44228/
N) and many more...

Comment: The current answer is incorrect, **only** the `log4j2.*` works. However, a new vulnerability has been discovered against which this mitigation is ineffective: [CVE-2021-45046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046) (though it is less likely that your application is vulnerable to that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: As [remarked by Markono1234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70345422/dlog4j-formatmsgnolookups-true-or-dlog4j2-formatmsgnolookups-true-which-is-c/70346062?noredirect=1#comment124397265_70346062) this particular property was introduced in Log4j 2.10 and the **only correct form** is `log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups` (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/6275d8aac4e392eacd81d942a1b97856c92b698f/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/Constants.java#L63)).

Most remaining properties have two forms: a pre-2.10 `log4j.*` legacy property name and a new normalized `log4j2.*` name. See [Log4j system properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#SystemProperties) for details:

> Note that beginning in Log4j 2.10, all system property names have been normalized to follow a consistent naming scheme. While the old property names are still supported for backwards compatibility, it is recommended to update configurations to use the new style.

Comment: Except that as mentioned on the [security page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html#CVE-2021-44228) only versions >= 2.10 support that property. Please adapt your answer. Also note that this system property does not protect against the newly discovered [CVE-2021-45046](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-45046) (though it is less likely that your application is vulnerable to that).