# log4j2.noFormatMsgLookup or log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups?

Tags: log4j

At https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html they use log4j2.noFormatMsgLookup and log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups

Which is the correct property: log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups or log4j2.noFormatMsgLookup? The last one seems a typo?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [-Dlog4j.formatMsgNoLookups=true OR -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true - which is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70345422/dlog4j-formatmsgnolookups-true-or-dlog4j2-formatmsgnolookups-true-which-is-c)

Answer (score 3):

It is `log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups` ([source](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/0043e9238af0efd9dbce462463e0fa1bf14e35b0/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/Constants.java#L64)).

The documentation error has been [fixed already](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/commit/ab2fb451d248702880a231646dace6b3ec9d98c2), but apparently the site was not updated yet.